# General linear group in infinite dimensions

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, infinite-dimensional-manifolds

Let $V$ be a vector space over the field $k$. Upon assuming the Axiom of Choice, we know that $V$ has a well-defined dimension $N$, and hence a well-defined basis $B$. Suppose that $N$ is not finite.

By definition, the *general linear group* of $V$ is the group of invertible linear transformations of $V$ (I hope this agrees with general conventions).
It defines the group of "invertible" ($N \times N$)-matrices over $k$ (if I am not mistaken).

If this is correct, then how should I define the special linear group ?

Now consider the linear group of matrices with row and column size $N$ which give rise to invertible linear transformations, but with only a finite number of nonzero entries off the diagonal, and only $1$ on the diagonal except possibly in a finite number of exceptions.

Does this group have a name ?

It seems that its special linear version coincides with the "geometrical" special linear group of $V$ -- that is, the group generated by all transvections -- so is this then a different special linear group than the aforementioned (to-be-defined) one ?

Comment: There is no special linear group in the infinite-dimensional case because there is no determinant; I think the general linear group might even be simple or something like that.

Comment: There still *might* be an analog of SL(∞,k)for a topological vector space k^∞ if there is a proper subgroup H of GL(∞,k) that is a deformation retract of GL(∞,k) and perhaps satisfies additional conditions expected of an SL.

Comment: I’ve seen the group you describe called the “finitary general linear group” and the “general finitary linear group”.